# Using require('jquery') with jsdom?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, npm, jsdom

I can use JSDOM's 'scripts' option to load jquery for scraping. However I was wondering if it was possible, and also better or worse, to use node's own require mechanism now npm includes jquery.

```
jsdom = require 'jsdom'

config =
  html: "<html><body></body></html>"
  scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js']

jsdom.env config, (err, window) ->
  $ = window.jQuery;
  $('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>")
  console.log(window.document.innerHTML)
```

All works fine and shows the updated document. But these days we can also run:

```
$ = require 'jquery'
$('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>")
```

Which I find neater - I'm just not quite sure of how to use jquery and jsdom in this newer manner. Specifically, where is the window object?

Answer (score 3):

Final working code below - it looks like node-jquery has an pre-built, empty document at 'body', to access the final document, you can just run .html() on it.

```
var $ = require('jquery')
$('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>")
console.log($("body").html())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to get at the window:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var ctx = jquery('<p>this is some markup</p>');
console.log(ctx[0].ownerDocument._parentWindow);
```

Use with caution, `._` properties are seen as *private*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. You are grabbing a specific instance of the jQuery object off of the JSDOM `window` object, whereas `require 'jquery'` would grab the jQuery module. You need a version of the `jQuery` object specific to that JSDOM window, instead, which means doing `$ = window.jQuery`

Comment: Thanks. But I believe JQuery includes jsdo, judging from the [announcemnet](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/e02619ec7d208d28). I've extended the answer to show that modifying the DOM using JQ does work (or at least doesn't fail). I'm just not sure where I can access the window object once I've finished modifying the document.